# Dodgy code Warnings by findbug

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a code like :

```
public void myfun(int value) throws ApplicationException{

    Object obj = new Object();

    if(value == 1){
        obj = <Call to other Service>
    } else if (value == 2){
        obj = <Call to other Service>
    }
    else {
       throw ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

I am getting warning by FindBug that Dead store to `obj`. I understand that This error is coming because obj is local variable and I am not using it in else statement. How should i handle this ?

Comment: if you are only using it inside the `if` then define it in the `if`

Comment: You could refactor to open with `if (value != true) { throw ApplicationException(); }` and then continue the rest of the function safe in the knowledge that it is true.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually there are multiple if else and input to the function is a integer. So I have to define it outside the if.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Seams like a way to go. but Is it a good Code practice ? One option can be to not use else at all. I wanted to understand good code practice.

Comment: It depends. Your example is too generic to say much.

Comment: Please post the actual code, in your example, there is a typo (`elseif`) and `obj` is never used so the code is kind of strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a dodgy warning, it's an unnecessary dead store. It has nothing to do with the else condition.

Your options are..

Use the variable, making the store not so dead any more..

```
Object obj; // don't new Object() here as we will only write over it

if(value == 1){
    obj = something();
} elseif (value == 2){
    obj = something();
} else {
   throw new ApplicationException();
}

useTheObject(obj);
```

Don't do the dead store in the first place. Variable not used? Take it out...

```
if(value == 1){
    something();
} elseif (value == 2){
    something();
} else {
   throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

Why store the value in the variable and not doing anything with it?